# Why is WordPress Breaking Custom Elements with Hyphens Into Element and Attribute?

Tags: wp-kses

## Background

I have a custom element in a page, which has a tagname of: `column-set`.

On the front end, that gets written as `<column -set="">`.

[image]

## Question

Why is this happening, and can it be changed? (I suspect it might have something to do with `wpautop`)

## Edit: More Info

I've found that kses might be the issue here. So I've added this to my `functions.php` file:

```
add_action( 'init', 'allow_custom_elem' );

function allow_custom_elem() {

    global $allowedposttags;

    $tags = [ 'column-set', 'test-element' ];

    foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {

        if ( ! isset( $allowedposttags[ $tag ] ) ) {
            $allowedposttags[ $tag ] = [
                'class' => true,
                'id' => true,
                'style' => true
            ];
        }

    }

    var_dump($allowedposttags);

}
```

After my `var_dump`, I see that in the allow tags, I now have:

```
'test-element' => 
  array (size=3)
    'class' => boolean true
    'id' => boolean true
    'style' => boolean true
```

But it's still being written to the page a `<test -element="">`.

Comment: Search for `kses` on our site.

Comment: @toscho, I've added the custom element to kses and it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

It's not `kses`. The culprit is this:

```
force_balance_tags()
```

When I remove that, things work. I'm not sure why it's breaking things, but I'll look into the source later.